# Databricks Error: Constructor public com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.FSUtilsParallel(org.apache.spark.SparkContext) is not whitelisted

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

When I execute the following dbutils code on our cluster `display(dbutils.fs.mounts())` I get the following error:

py4j.security.Py4JSecurityException: Constructor public com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.FSUtilsParallel(org.apache.spark.SparkContext) is not whitelisted.

Can someone let me know what could be the cause (and remedy)

The full error message is as follows:

```
Py4JError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-1817294295345329> in <module>
----> 1 display(dbutils.fs.mounts())

/local_disk0/tmp/1684505420167-0/dbutils.py in __getattr__(self, item)
    517             jvm_dbutils = sc._jvm.com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils
    518             fs = self.FSHandler(jvm_dbutils.FSUtils,
--> 519                                 jvm_dbutils.FSUtilsParallel(sc._jsc.sc()),
    520                                 jvm_dbutils.DBUtilsCore(sc._jsc.sc(),
    521                                                         self.shell.sqlContext._ssql_ctx),

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1567         answer = self._gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1568         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1569             answer, self._gateway_client, None, self._fqn)
   1570 
   1571         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    125     def deco(*a, **kw):
    126         try:
--> 127             return f(*a, **kw)
    128         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    129             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)
```

Any thoughts?

Cluster configuration
[image]

Comment: something to do with Access mode and Shared cluster? Can you post a pic of your cluster config? At top you have "Policy" and "Access mode". UI might be different if you are looking at legacy UI and not the preview version. Here is an example of what I'm looking for: https://community.databricks.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=ORIGINAL_Png&versionId=0688Y00000G1fou&operationContext=CHATTER&contentId=05T8Y00001ExKlO

Comment: Hi @Kashyap, thanks for reaching out. I have updated the question with the cluster configuration

Comment: do you have credential passthrough enabled? Is it a high concurrency cluster? It's supposed to be a "legacy" way of doing things and causes this error some time.

Comment: Hi @Kashyap, can you let me know how to determine if I have credential passthrough enabled?

Comment: Updated my answer with more info. Can you create new clusters? If yes, then can you create one with Access mode set to "Single User" and try running `display(dbutils.fs.mounts())` on it? If not then ask your admin what's in "Interactive (All-purpose) test cluster" policy.  --- I also notice you have a fairly old version of DBR (7.x), though it's still supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this might have something do with Databricks trying to secure things by segregating runtime for each user when you allow multiple users to use same cluster.

Some combination of Cluster Mode/Access Mode (High Concurrency/Shared/Single/...) and Credentials Passthrough settings causes this.

If it's dev, I recommend you simply use some different Access Mode (like Single User) and work around all these issues.

Also read that `spark.databricks.pyspark.enablePy4JSecurity false` helped some folks. But clearly not something you want to do in prod without understanding what it means.

See some info:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/credential-passthrough/adls-passthrough#--limitations
- https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D53f00001r3IR9CAM/constructor-public-comdatabricksbackenddaemondbutilsfsutilsparallel-is-not-whitelisted-when-mounting-a-s3-bucket

--- edit ---

As described under "[Shared access mode limitations](https://docs.databricks.com/data-governance/unity-catalog/compute.html#shared-limitations)": *Cannot use Scala, R, RDD APIs, or clients that directly read the data from cloud storage, **such as DBUtils**.*

Your cluster mode is "Custom", which is basically "one of the legacy modes". So limitations of "Shared" mode aren't applicable, but this is the only restriction that says `DBUtils isn't allowed`.

Comment: I tried ```spark.databricks.pyspark.enablePy4JSecurity false``` but got a syntax error. It didn't like the false

Comment: Format depends on how you're setting it (CLI, python, scala, web UI, Terraform, ...). See relevant docs.

Comment: Hi @Kashyap, I have checked out the links you suggested, however there doesn't appear to be a solution. As I mentioned, the syntax error was due to the false attribute. Can you think of any other attributes to to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the simillar issue . When i changed the access mode to "No isolation shared" from "Shared" mode , it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Access mode "Custom". That is legacy.

Accessing DBFS in Access mode as "Shared" requires the `ANY FILES` permission (see [here](https://Accessing%20DBFS%20in%20Shared%20mode%20requires%20the%20ANY%20FILES%20permission.%20See%20here%20and%20here.)). Note that setting `ANY FILES` permission should be taken with caution. If you use Access mode as "Single User", you should not have this problem.