# Java SQL Driver Manager not working in Unit Catalog

Tags: pyspark, databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

This is working in normal databricks workspace but not working in Unity Catalog

```
driver_manager = spark._sc._gateway.jvm.java.sql.DriverManager
con = driver_manager.getConnection(connection_string)

statement = con.prepareCall(query)
statement.execute()

statement.close()
con.close()
```

Following code throwing an error: `py4j.security.Py4JSecurityException: Method public static java.sql.Connection java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(java.lang.String) throws java.sql.SQLException is not whitelisted on class class java.sql.DriverManager`

I have tried to pass seperated arguments for getConnection method, but sounds like this method have changed in Unity Catalog
`sqlsUrl = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{host}:{port};database={dbname}"`

```
username = 'test'
password = 'test'
con = jvm.java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(sqlsUrl, username,password)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cluster with Unity Catalog enabled and Access Mode set to "Shared", has many restrictions to isolate jobs from different users running on same (shared) cluster.

As they put it: *"so that users can’t access unprivileged data through the cluster."*

See

- [Access mode limitations](https://docs.databricks.com/en/compute/access-mode-limitations.html#shared-limitations)
- [Allowlist](https://docs.databricks.com/en/data-governance/unity-catalog/manage-privileges/allowlist.html) -- I do not recommend doing this for spark jars, because it'll defeat the purpose of these restrictions, it's like granting root privileges to every user on a machine.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76290750/496289) has some more info/links.

Solution is to simply use a cluster with Access Mode set to "Single User". Anyway your jobs would run as some user, so usually you'll have no reason to have a "Shared" cluster in production.

---

PS: Using `spark._sc._gateway.jvm.java.sql.DriverManager` to create a connection and executing some query is a really weird thing to do in pyspark. You might have chosen the wrong way to do something that you need done.

Comment: Correct , solution for this is to create cluster with policy Personal Compute.